# Display emoji with TextView

Tags: android, textview, emoji

I don't know how to reveals some text including emoji character with TextView. Please suggest me how to convert the emoji character to image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/andinrajesh/EmojiPopup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try with the  regular expression: "[\ue415\ue056\ue057]". 
visit following links also.

https://github.com/ohmrefresh/Emoji-TextView

https://github.com/sharakova/EmojiTextView

http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-add-smileyemojis-in-edittext.html

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks!!. All link help me a lot

Comment: its my pleasure to help.

Comment: This does not work when you have list of unicodes and need to display in RecyclerView!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put some small emoji imaged along with your text use `ImageSpan` and `SpannableStringBuilder` classes.